# Can Notepad++ execute a definable command that will be executed when opening a certain filetype?

Tags: notepad++

Is it possible to always execute the "Pretty print (XML Only, with line breaks)" command of the XML Plugin when opening any .xml file or "JSFormat" of the JSTool plugin when opening a .json file? I currently punch in way too many Ctrl-Alt-Shift combinations.

Comment: did you try the below solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is as follows:

- Install [PythonScript](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/) plugin for Notepad++
- Write a python script which accesses the plugin menu and its tools
- Make sure the script runs at startup of Notepad++

---

### Install PythonScript Plugin

- If your Notepad++ version is above **7.6.3**, then follow this [GUIDE](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above), else you can install it via plugin manager under Plugins menu
- If you face any issues in the above step, refer [this](https://github.com/bruderstein/PythonScript/issues/109) and the installation guide [here](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/docs/latest/usage.html)
- This assumes that you have Python interpreter **v2.7** installed, if not you can install it from [here](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/)

**Note:** For Notepad++ **v7.8**, here's an update from the collaborator of the plugin from [github](https://github.com/bruderstein/PythonScript/issues/102#issuecomment-544276596),

> See https://github.com/bruderstein/PythonScript/releases/tag/v1.5.2 for a version compatible with the current N++ 7.8 release. Pythonscript will be also available again with the next N++ release from PluginAdmin.

### Python Script

- The script should do the following:

  - Check the language type of the opened file
  - Execute the plugin tool based on the type
- To check language type, use the member function [`getCurrentLang`](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/docs/latest/notepad.html#Notepad.getCurrentLang)
- To execute the plugin tool, use the member function [`runPluginCommand`](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/docs/latest/notepad.html#Notepad.runPluginCommand)

```py
if notepad.getCurrentLang() == LANGTYPE.XML:
    notepad.runPluginCommand("XML Tools","Pretty print (XML only - with line breaks)")

elif notepad.getCurrentLang() == LANGTYPE.JSON:
    notepad.runPluginCommand("JSTool","JSFormat")
```

### Startup

- Append the above script to `startup.py` (*Refer [this](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/docs/latest/usage.html#startup) to find `startup.py`*)
- Also make sure **Initialisation** is set to `ATSTARTUP` in the Python Script Configuration window (*You can find this under Plugins->PythonScripts->Configuration*)

---

### References

- [Notepad++ community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/16534/could-everyone-tell-me-how-can-use-notepad-plugins-by-a-script/2)
- [PythonScript plugin documentation](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/docs/latest/notepad.html)

Comment: Beautiful, but I am having issues on my machine. I upgraded to 7.8 and PythonScript is available but does not seem to run any scripts (some of the example scripts seem to to something, but typically stop with an access violation error, startup.py does not seem to have an effect). I think I'll wait until v7.8 is supported by PythonScripts and try again.